# laravel eloquent with pivot and another table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 4 table `categories`, `initiatives`, a pivot table for the "Many To Many" relationship `category_initiative` and `initiativegroup` table related with initiatives table with `initiatives`.`initiativesgroup_id` with one to many relation.
With pure sql I retrive the information I need with:

```
SELECT categories.id, categories.description, initiatives.id, initiatives.description, initiativegroups.group
FROM categories
LEFT JOIN category_initiative ON categories.id = category_initiative.category_id
LEFT JOIN initiatives ON category_initiative.initiative_id = initiatives.id
LEFT JOIN initiativegroups ON initiatives.initiativegroup_id = initiativegroups.id
WHERE categories.id = '40'
```

How can I use eloquent model to achieve same results?

Comment: Do you have your model classes and relationships between them created already?

Comment: Yes all tablet are realated correctly. Using nova all relationship are retrived correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the record..
with my original relationship, but changing table name as alex suggest, in my controller:

```
$inits = Category::with('initiative.group')->find($id_cat);
```

simple and clean

Answer (score 1):

Since you have such a specific query touching multiple tables, one possibility is to use query builder. That would preserve the precision of the query, retrieving only the data you specifically need. That would look something like this:

```
$categories = DB::table('categories')
            ->select([
                'categories.id',
                'categories.description',
                'initiatives.id',
                'initiatives.description',
                'initiativegroups.group',
            ])
            ->leftJoin('category_initiative', 'categories.id', '=', 'category_initiative.category_id')
            ->leftJoin('initiatives', 'category_initiative.initiative_id', '=', 'initiatives.id')
            ->leftJoin('initiativegroups', 'initiatives.initiativegroup_id', '=', 'initiativegroups.id')
            ->where('categories.id', '=', 40)
            ->get();
```

Comment: First of all thanks! No way for the same result with eloquent? I would like to use only one way ti access db... Or May Be not so efficente in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In your models define the relationships:
Category.php model

```
public function initiatives()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Initiative');
}
```

Initiative.php model (If has many categories change to belongs to many)

```
public function category()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

Then maybe change your initiativegroup -> groups table, and then create a pivot table called group_initiative. Create model for group. Group.php and define the relationship:

```
public function initiatives()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Initiative');
}
```

Then you can also add the following relationship definition to the Initiative.php model

```
public function group()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Group');
}
```

That should get you started.

Comment: thanks @alex!  All relationship are ok.  Initiatives and categorie table are linked with a ManyToMany relation, and witt:  $category = Category::find($id_cat)->load('Initiative');     I can get all initiative models related to selected categories model.  initiatives table is related to group with id_group belongsTo id in group table. But how get group description in my collection?

Comment: $initiative->group->description